# How to use jsdoc on vue3 props without typescript?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, jsdoc, vue-composition-api

```
const props = defineProps({
items: {
    /** @type {{new(): Color[] }} */
    type: Array,
    required: true,
  },
  selectedColor: {
    type: Object,
    required: true,
  },
  composable: {
    type: Function,
    required: true
  }
})
```

We don't use typescript so I'm trying to add types with just jsdoc and typescript interface files.

Items is correctly typed as an Array of Color.
How do I specify the type of selectedColor as Color?
Also how would I specify the type of composable?

None of these work

```
const props = defineProps({
  selected: {
    /** @type {Color} */
    type: Object,
    required: true,
  },
  composable: {
    /** @type {function(): number} */
    type: Function,
    required: true
  }
})
```

```
const props = defineProps({
  selected: {
    /** @type {{ new(): Color}} */
    type: Object,
    required: true,
  },
  composable: {
    /** @type {{ new(): number}} */
    type: Function,
    required: true
  }
})
```

Answer (score 5):

I got a working solution.

```
const props = defineProps({
  selectedColor: {
    /** @type import('vue').PropType<Color> */
    type: Object,
    required: true
  },
  setColor: {
    /** @type import('vue').PropType<(color: Color) => void> */
    type: Function,
    required: true,
  }
})
```

The autocomplete works in this case but VSC complains about the Function type.

```
Type 'FunctionConstructor' is not assignable to type 'PropType<(color: Color) => void>'.
  Type 'FunctionConstructor' is not assignable to type '() => (color: Color) => void'.ts(2322)
```

Replacing Function with Object fixes the error, but then the props are less specific.

```
const props = defineProps({
  setColor: {
    /** @type import('vue').PropType<(color: Color) => void> */
    type: Object,
    required: true,
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer indeed works, but in my case it looked more like this:

```
/** @template T; @typedef {import("vue").PropType<T>} PropType<T> */
/**
 * @typedef Book
 * @property {string} title
 * @property {string} author
*/

export default {
  ...
  props: {
    book: {
      /** @type {PropType<Book>} */
      type: Object,
      default: () => ({}),
    },
  },
  data() { }, // data decl was needed so types are recognized
  ...
};
```

I had to add an empty data declaration (my component only needed data from props) for the types to be recognized within `computed`, `methods`, `mounted()`, etc.